# Form in a Joomla Module

Tags: html, model-view-controller, joomla

Is it a good idea to put a none-AJAX form into a Joomla module and process the form not in a component's controller but in the module itself? Is there a cooking recipe for this?

Comment: I must refine my question: If I am doing so, what action tag has to be defined in the form?

Comment: You can use a form without an action, then grab the data when the forum has been submitted in `mod_mymodule.php`

Answer (score 0):

That's completely fine.

Components shouldn't use used to process a modules data, unless the module has been specifically developed to be part of the component.

Take **com_users** for example. This component is used to do all processing for registration, login, logout, profile and reminder/reset of passwords. The login module then simply displays the form and performs a few checks.